# How to pass a hash object to a HAML tag

Tags: ruby, haml

Please consider this example:

```
- user_links_params = _user_link_params(current_user)

%a{ :'data-msgstore-path' => user_links_params[:'data-msgstore-path'],
  :'data-user_id' => user_links_params[:'data-user_id'],
  :class => user_links_params[:class],
}
  / too many html tags and stuff to fit in a simple link_to
```

I would be nice to fit all this in a simple statement like the following:

```
%a[_user_link_params(current_user)]
  / too many html tags and stuff to fit in a simple link_to
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and you were close:

```
%a{_user_link_params(current_user)}
```

From the [HAML reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html):

> For example, if you defined
>
> ```
> def hash1
>   {:bread => 'white', :filling => 'peanut butter and jelly'}
> end
>
> def hash2
>   {:bread => 'whole wheat'}
> end
> ```
>
> then `%sandwich{hash1, hash2, :delicious => true}/` would compile to:
>
> ```
> <sandwich bread='whole wheat' delicious='true' filling='peanut butter and jelly' />
> ```

Comment: Little warning, the method needs to return a hash and cannot return nil